# How ARCore recognize images with repetitive pattern

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arcore, android-augmented-reality

I create generator of augmented images. By contrast changer (gimp or from scratch using python), I can reach 100 score from bad image with 0-5 score, checking through arcoreimg.exe. Main question is why image, which has 5 score (pinned link), may has 100 score, when image has repetitive pattern?

"Best practices

Tips for selecting reference images

--Avoid images with repetitive features." from google

Concrete example

[That is 5 score image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4b4s.jpg)

[That is 100 score image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LguJU.png)

Comment: It's a little challenging to understand what you're asking--please make your question clear.

Comment: An image with repeating patterns is poorly recognized through the application (arcoreimg.exe). But the image, with a higher level of contrast, is well recognized. Why?